# loading an image using the static tag from a static path

Tags: django, tags, block, static-content

I am unable to load an image on my index page using the following syntax

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <-!---This is the statement-->
   <-div data-src=  "{% static "bootstrap/images/slider/slider-img1.jpg" %}">
   <-/div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I added an extra `- (dash)` in the div because the post had difficulty displaying it.

Anyways I am getting the error

```
Invalid block tag on line 69: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

I think this is a directory structure. My directory currently looks like this

```
|_mainApp
|  |_______index.html ------>This is where i am trying to run the statement
|_templates
|  |_______base.html ------->The statement works fine in the base
|_static
   |_bootstrap
|_CenterApp
   |_settings.py
   |_urls.py
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting that error is that a location issue and the content cant be found ? or is it something else ?

Comment: You need to `{% load 'static' %}` at the top of your template before trying to use the `static` template tag.

Comment: yes that did the trick thank you. Could you please put that as the answer

Comment: The quotes around 'static' were too much, on my side. But it worked well with just static. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Whenever you use `{% extend "some_page.html" %}` and you need some links with static url you can use `{{STATIC_URL}}` instead of `{% static "/some/link/" %}`

So in your case, use it as:

```
<-div data-src=  "{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap/images/slider/slider-img1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 5):

use

```
  {% load staticfiles %}
```

below you have extended your base.html

In django template it is important to call {% load staticfiles %} whenever you are using static in template. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static)